# Why does "unsigned int64_t" give an error in C?

Tags: c, gcc, unsigned, int64

Why does the following program give an error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    unsigned int64_t i = 12;
    printf("%lld\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
 In function 'main':
5:19: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'i'
  unsigned int64_t i = 12;
                   ^
5:19: error: 'i' undeclared (first use in this function)
5:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

But, If I remove the **unsigned** keyword, it's working fine. So,
**Why does `unsigned int64_t i` give me an error?**

Comment: You need `#include <stdint.h>`. You should also be using `uint64_t` rather than `unsigned int64_t`.

Comment: And once you include the correct header file, why not use the `uint64_t` type?

Comment: @PaulR getting same error.

Comment: @rsp: did you fix *both* problems ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot apply the `unsigned` modifier on the type `int64_t`. It only works on `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long`.

You probably want to use `uint64_t` which is the unsigned counterpart of `int64_t`.

Also note that `int64_t` et al. are defined in the header `stdint.h`, which you should include if you want to use these types.

Answer (score 6):

`int64_t` is not some builtin type. Try adding `#include <stdint.h>` to define such types;  then use `uint64_t` which means what you appear to intend.

Answer (score 2):

`int64_t` is a *typedef name*. N1570 §7.20.1.1 p1:

> The typedef name **int*N*_t** designates a signed integer type with width *N*, no padding
>   bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, **int8_t** denotes such a signed
>   integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

Standard lists what combinations are legal in §6.7.2 p2:

> - char
> - signed char
> - unsigned char
> - short, signed short, short int, or signed short int
> - unsigned short, or unsigned short int
> - int, signed, or signed int
> - unsigned, or unsigned int
> - long, signed long, long int, or signed long int
> - unsigned long, or unsigned long int
> - long long, signed long long, long long int, or
>     signed long long int
> - unsigned long long, or unsigned long long int
>
> ...
>
> - typedef name

<sub>Types that are not relevant to the question have been removed from the list.</sub>

Note how you cannot mix typedef name with `unsigned`.

---

To use unsigned 64-bit type, you need to:

- Use `uint64_t` (note the leading `u`) without `unsigned` specifier.

  ```
  uint64_t i = 12;
  ```
- Include `stdint.h` (or `inttypes.h`) where `uint64_t` is defined.
- To print `uint64_t` you need to include `inttypes.h` and use `PRIu64`:

  ```
  printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", i);
  ```

  You can also or cast to `unsigned long long` which is 64-bits or more. However it's preferable to avoid casting when it's not strictly necessary, so the you should prefer `PRIu64` method.

  ```
  printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)i);
  ```

Comment: `printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)i);` - **NO**. `inttypes.h` is a required header, so it will exist. Otherwise delete the compiler, it might have other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` of `int64_t` is something like:

```
typedef signed long long int int64_t;
```

So, `unsigned int64_t i;`  becomes something like:

```
unsigned signed long long int i;
```

Which is obviously a compiler error.

So, use `int64_t` instead of `unsigned int64_t`.

Also, add `#include <stdint.h>` header file in your program.