# CHAR_BIT replacement

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

`CHAR_BIT` defines the number of bits per character. But it is an old macro. Similar macros have been replaced in recent C++ standards.

Is there a more modern replacement for `CHAR_BIT` in C++11/14/17?

Comment: I don't think `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits()` is better than `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: I don't understand the motivation of this question. If everything that's old must be replaced, we'd never have anything stable. Why do you think it's necessary to replace `CHAR_BIT`, and what's wrong with it?

Comment: Wow. Keep calm. Where did I say anything about my motivation? Where did I say CHAR_BIT is wrong? Or a replacement would be *necessary*? I think templated code can have advantages but I was mainly just curious.

Comment: @DeiDei : Perhaps not, but `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::digits` for example is perhaps better than `sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT`, so it is at least consistent if you choose to use it for the larger types too.  Note too that `digits` is a data-member, not a member-function.

Comment: One has to use `std::numeric_limits<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>::digits` within templates accepting signed types. A bit verbose, I must say.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The number of non-sign bits is provided by `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits`, so it can be determined by:

```
std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits
```

Note the use of the `unsigned` qualifier to ensure there are no sign bits.

Comment: One has to use `std::numeric_limits<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>::digits` within templates accepting signed types. A bit verbose compared to `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T)`, I must say.

Comment: @EmileCormier why would you do that though? a signed type has the same number of bits as it's unsigned counterpart, so I am suggesting you use the unsigned qualifier regardless of the type of the other operands involved in an expression. If your point needs elaboration to explain why this is useful, post an answer.

Comment: You can't apply the `unsigned` qualifier to types such as `int64_t`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626223/why-unsigned-int64-t-gives-an-error-in-c

Comment: Oh, I think I misinterpreted your answer. You're proposing `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits * sizeof(T)` instead of `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T)`. My bad.

Comment: @EmileCormier Indeed - I answered the question ;-)

Comment: Yep, brainfart. I was doing a lot of `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T)` in my code and that was still stuck in my brain when I read your answer.